# Cambiar formato a una columna de datagridview enlazada a MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Porque cuando ejecuto la consulta en phpmyadmin o la consola de mysql si me sale en el formato que yo quiero en horas como se muestra en la imagen

Consulta

```
SELECT asistencia.Matricula,prestadores.Nombre,
       DATE_FORMAT(asistencia.fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') AS Fecha,
       DATE_FORMAT(asistencia.hora_entrada,'%r') AS 
       Hora_Entrada,DATE_FORMAT(asistencia.hora_salida,'%r') AS 
       Hora_Salida, 
IF(DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%W')='Sunday',SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , 
    asistencia.hora_entrada, asistencia.hora_salida 
    ))*120),SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , asistencia.hora_entrada, 
asistencia.hora_salida ))*60)) AS Total_Horas_Por_Dia 
FROM asistencia 
JOIN prestadores ON prestadores.matricula=asistencia.matricula 
ORDER BY asistencia.hora_entrada ASC
```

[image: Consulta en phpMyadmin 1]

y a la hora de visualizarlo en el datagridview me aparece con el siguiente formato

[image: Formato en Vb]

Intente con esta linea de código para cambiar el estilo de la celda

```
Checador.DataGridView1.Columns("Total_Horas_Por_Dia").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss"
```

Pero me sale este error...

[image: Error]

**Mi pregunta es... ¿Se puede cambiar el formato de la ultima columna del datagridview de tal manera que quedé igual que en phpmyadmin?**

**De antemano gracias**

Comment: ¿Cómo determinas que el campo `asistencia.hora_entrada` y `asistencia.hora_salida` están dentro del mismo día? Lo pregunto porque tienes otro campo `asistencia.fecha`.

Comment: Los campos son de tipo "datetime"

Answer (score 2):

Estuve investigando y tuve una solución, quizás muy poco elegante pero ahí va.

Hice diferentes pruebas y por más que intenté la columna del `datagridview` no aceptaba más allá de las `23:00:00` y agregaba el día `1.09:08:00` ya que la consulta devuelve un dato tipo `TIME` y lo que hice fue convertir en texto con `CAST`.

Primero cargas el control con los datos de `mysql`

```
Private Sub cargar_horas()
    Try
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(conexion_base)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT " &
                                            "CAST(IF(DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%W')='Sunday', SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, asistencia.hora_entrada, " &
                                            "asistencia.hora_salida))*120), " &
                                            "SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, asistencia.hora_entrada, asistencia.hora_salida ))*60)) AS char) " &
                                            "AS Total_Horas_Por_Dia_text, " &
                                            "IF(DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%W')='Sunday', SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, asistencia.hora_entrada, " &
                                            "asistencia.hora_salida))*120), " &
                                            "SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, asistencia.hora_entrada, asistencia.hora_salida ))*60)) " &
                                            "AS Total_Horas_Por_Dia FROM asistencia;", con)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Hubo un error al cargar los datos", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Ahí pongo 2 columnas una tipo texto para visualizar y la otra que (como sugerencia) puedes ocultar para realizar cálculos con las horas sin volver a hacer la conversión.

Y luego le das formato.

```
 ''' Debes ajustar los indices de las columnas

 Private Sub formato_grid()
    With DataGridView1
        .Columns(0).Name = "Total_Horas_Por_Dia_text"
        .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "Total horas por día"
        .Columns(0).Visible = True
        .Columns(0).ReadOnly = True

        ''' Esta columna en .Visible hay que establecerla en False
        .Columns(1).Visible = True
        .Columns(1).ReadOnly = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Y te queda así:

[image: datagridview]

Espero que sea de tu ayuda o a seguir investigando. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Lo resolví modificando la consulta

```
   SELECT asistencia.Matricula,prestadores.Nombre,
       DATE_FORMAT(asistencia.fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') AS Fecha,
       DATE_FORMAT(asistencia.hora_entrada,'%r') AS 
       Hora_Entrada,DATE_FORMAT(asistencia.hora_salida,'%r') AS 
       Hora_Salida, 
IF(DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%W')='Sunday',TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , 
    asistencia.hora_entrada, asistencia.hora_salida 
    ))*120),'%H:%i:00'),SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , asistencia.hora_entrada, 
asistencia.hora_salida ))*60)) AS Total_Horas_Por_Dia 
FROM asistencia 
JOIN prestadores ON prestadores.matricula=asistencia.matricula 
ORDER BY asistencia.hora_entrada ASC
```

Usando el **TIME_FORMAT** para así poder darle el formato que quería en horas de tal manera que se logrará visualizar en el datagridview.

Quedando con el formato deseado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]