# Sumar Horas en columna de datagridview VB.NET enlazado a mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, windows-forms

Estoy creando un formulario en cual genera un reporte de las horas realizadas dentro de un rango de fechas... cosa que ya hice, pero no con el formato deseado...

Este es el codigo que uso para la sumatoria de horas

```
   Sub horas_realizadas()
        Try
            Dim consulta As String
            Dim Fi As String = Reporte.DtpInicio.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            Dim Ff As String = Reporte.DtpFinal.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            consulta = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y'),DATE_FORMAT(hora_entrada,'%r'),DATE_FORMAT(hora_salida,'%r'), IF(DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%W')='Sunday',SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , asistencia.hora_entrada, asistencia.hora_salida ))*120),SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , asistencia.hora_entrada, asistencia.hora_salida ))*60)) AS horas_realizadas FROM asistencia where matricula = '" & Reporte.matricula.Text & "' AND fecha BETWEEN '" & Fi & "' AND '" & Ff & "' GROUP BY fecha asc"
            adaptador = New MySqlDataAdapter(consulta, Con2)
            datos = New DataSet
            adaptador.Fill(datos, "asistencia")


            Dim horas As TimeSpan

            For Each row As DataRow In datos.Tables("asistencia").Rows

                horas += (row.Item("horas_realizadas"))
            Next



            datos.Tables("asistencia").Rows.Add("Total de horas:", " ", " ", horas)
            Reporte.txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(horas)
            Reporte.DataGridView1.DataSource = datos
            Reporte.DataGridView1.DataMember = "asistencia"

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Y como resultado sale esto:

[image: RESULTADO]

No esta mal el resultado, solo que no es el formato buscado ya traté de cambiar el formato del tiempo de la consulta como lo hice en esta [Pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277283/cambiar-formato-a-una-columna-de-datagridview-enlazada-a-mysql) pero no me funciona.

El formato deseado es **45**

De antemano gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví usando el **TIME_TO_SEC** para de esta manera que devuelva los segundos en la consulta dejando asi la consulta...

El query quedaria de la siguiente forma...

```
> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') as
> FECHA,DATE_FORMAT(hora_entrada,'%r') as
> Hora_Entrada,DATE_FORMAT(hora_salida,'%r') AS Hora_Salida, 
>           IF(DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%W')='Sunday',TIME_TO_SEC(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE
> ,     asistencia.hora_entrada, asistencia.hora_salida    
> ))*120)),TIME_TO_SEC(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE ,
> asistencia.hora_entrada,     asistencia.hora_salida ))*60))) AS
> Total_Horas_Por_Dia FROM asistencia where matricula 
>     = '" & Reporte.matricula.Text & "' AND fecha BETWEEN '" & Fi & "' AND '" & Ff & "'GROUP BY fecha ASC
```

y ya despues saco las horas dividiendo el resultado quedando el codigo de la siguiente manera...

```
Sub horas_realizadas()
        Try
            Dim consulta As String
            Dim Fi As String = Reporte.DtpInicio.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            Dim Ff As String = Reporte.DtpFinal.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            consulta = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') as FECHA,DATE_FORMAT(hora_entrada,'%r') as Hora_Entrada,DATE_FORMAT(hora_salida,'%r') AS Hora_Salida, IF(DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%W')='Sunday',TIME_TO_SEC(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , asistencia.hora_entrada, asistencia.hora_salida ))*120)),TIME_TO_SEC(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE , asistencia.hora_entrada, asistencia.hora_salida ))*60))) AS Total_Horas_Por_Dia FROM asistencia where matricula = '" & Reporte.matricula.Text & "' AND fecha BETWEEN '" & Fi & "' AND '" & Ff & "' GROUP BY fecha ASC"
            adaptador = New MySqlDataAdapter(consulta, Con2)
            datos = New DataSet
            adaptador.Fill(datos, "asistencia")


            Dim horas As Integer


            For Each row As DataRow In datos.Tables("asistencia").Rows

  'Aqui es la división que mencionaba para sacar las horas a partir del total de segundos devueltos'
                horas += (row.Item("Total_Horas_Por_Dia") / 60) / 60

            Next


            datos.Tables("asistencia").Rows.Add("Total de horas:", " ", " ", horas)
            Reporte.DataGridView1.DataSource = datos
            Reporte.DataGridView1.DataMember = "asistencia"
            Reporte.txtTotal2.Text = horas.ToString(horas)


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Y asi en el formulario

[image: ORASI]